# Definition of differentiable map that preserves orientations

Tags: smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra, orientation, pullback

I'm reading Frank W.Warner's "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups". In page 139, he defines the differentiable map that preserves orientations:

> Let M and N be orientable n-dimensional manifolds, and let $\psi: M\to N$
> be a **differentiable map**. We say that $\psi$ preserves orientations if **the induced
> map $\delta \psi:\Lambda_n^*(N)\to \Lambda_n^*(M)$** maps the component $\Lambda_n^*(N)-O$ determining the orientation on N into the component of $\Lambda_n^*(M)-O$ determining the
> orientation on M. Equivalently, $\psi$ is orientation-preserving if $d \psi$ sends
> oriented bases of the tangent spaces to M into oriented bases of the tangent
> spaces to N.

But I can't see what the map $\delta \psi:\Lambda_n^*(N)\to \Lambda_n^*(M)$ is when $\psi: M\to N$
is only a differentiable map. And I think all the arguments make sense if $\psi: M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: What is the $\Lambda^*_n$?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz presumably the induced map on the $n$-th exterior product of the cotangent bundle

Comment: I thought so. A better question would be, why can't you (OP) define $\delta\phi:\Lambda^*_n(N)\to\Lambda^*_n(M)$?

Comment: @ JackozeeHakkiuz $\Lambda_n^*(N)$ is the exterior n-bundle over  N.

Comment: What is the usual definition of $\delta \psi:\Lambda_n^*(N)\to \Lambda_n^*(M)$ that you know?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz For every $m\in M$, there is a $\delta \psi: \Lambda_n^*(N_{\psi(m)})\to \Lambda_n^*(M_m)$. But I can't assemble these maps to a map $\delta \psi: \Lambda_n^*(N)\to \Lambda_n^*(M)$, because $\psi$ is not bijective.

Comment: @ArcticChar For every $m\in M$, there is a $\delta \psi: \Lambda_n^*(N_{\psi(m)})\to \Lambda_n^*(M_m)$, the extension of the transpose of $d \psi_m$. But I can't assemble these maps to a map $\delta \psi: \Lambda_n^*(N)\to \Lambda_n^*(M)$, because $\psi$ is not bijective.

Comment: Ah, yes. I can see the problem. I think you are right and there is a mistake in the book. I'll think about it.

Comment: I'm convinced now that it is a mistake. Has the author introduced the bundle of $n$-vectors? I think the statement makes sense and is actually correct between these bundles.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz OK. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, if $f:M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism (there is an open cover $\mathcal U$ of $M$ such that $f|U:U\to f[U]$ is a diffeo for every $U\in\mathcal U$) then there is an induced map in the *same direction* $\Lambda_n^* f:\Lambda_n^*M\to\Lambda_n^*$ given by
$$\Lambda_n^* f \omega (v_1,\dots,v_n) = \omega((df)^{-1}v_1,\dots,(df)^{-1}v_n)$$
for every $\omega\in M_p^*$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n\in N_{f(p)}$.

Comment: But the condition that $df$ sends oriented bases to oriented bases works in any case. I think the author tried to define orientation-preserving maps without having to dualize.